# Naming AutoRest generated method names using Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, autorest

I was playing around with the [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) and [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) projects. My Web API controller has a method called `GetAllAsync`. When I generate a client for the service, the client has an interface `IResourcesOperations`, where `Resources` is the name of the controller.

The interface has a method called `GetAllAsyncWithHttpMessagesAsync`. Then there's a static class called `ResourcesOperationsExtensions` that defines a method called `GetAllAsync` and one called `GetAllAsyncAsync`. The first one actually runs the second one of a new thread from the thread pool (`Task.Factory.StartNew`). Anyone know the reason for that?

I found that I can decorate my controller action method with the attribute

```
    [SwaggerOperation("GetResources")]
```

This will generate a method on the client class called `GetResourcesWithHttpMessagesAsync` and remove all methods for this web API action from the interface and extension method class.

Now my question are, why are these three methods generated by default?

And is there a way to generate a client with a method named `GetResources` (i.e. get rid of that WithHttpMessagesAsync suffix) or even `GetAllAsync`?

Answer (score 2):

AutoRest (at least the more recent versions) generates classes with the suffix `Extensions`. These classes contain extension methods on the proxy interface which allow you to call the methods with shortened method names like the ones you are after.

Simply add a

```
@using TheNameSpace.OfYour.Client.Extensions
```

to any class in which you need access to these shortened method names.

Answer (score 1):

AutoRest basically always generates an `<operation-name>Async` (extension) method for people who want to use async/await and a synchronous version `<operation-name>` that blocks.

You did not say what your method actually returns or is supposed to do, but I assume you want one less `Async` in your generated method names.

In that case you have to convince Swashbuckle to strip the `Async` suffix when it generates the Swagger, i.e. override the generated method name to `GetAll`. AutoRest does not try to be smart when it sees a Swagger method definition with name `GetAllAsync`.